# Get configured product from configurable in cart

Tags: cart, configurable-product, simple-product

I need to get the simple product of a configurable product in the cart.  Right now I am getting the configurable product.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Get Simple Product from Configurable in Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027524/get-simple-product-from-configurable-in-cart)

```
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        $simpleProduct = $option->getProduct()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simpleproducts = $conf_prod->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simpleproducts as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getSku();
        echo $simple_product->getName();
    }
endif;
```

Assuming $_product as configurable product, you can get all the associated products belonging to this particular configurable product using the above code.
Thanks

Comment: I'm only trying to get a single configured product, not all associated products.

Comment: $simpleProductId = 4; $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable') ->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId); $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]); echo $product->getId();

Comment: go from configurable product -> simple product.  not simple product -> configurable product

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what exactly you want to achieve to do?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is save simple product sku and configurable product id when it cart configurable product.
Simple Product sku by `$_item->getSku();`

You can get cart simple product details by load of product model

```
$SimpleProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku());
```

Configurable product by  `$_item->getProduct()`

```
$ConfigurableProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());



$_item->getProduct()->getTypeId=='configurable'
```